# Trouble Install Face_Recognition Python Module

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition

System: Windows 10

Python 3.6 using PyCharm.

I tried installing the face_recognition python module from Pycharm and received this error:

> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

The proposed solution was to run it from the command line in the file directory, but an error still persisted when I did that.

I've been using pip3 install face_recognition.

> Command "c:\users*\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y2duvqsp\dlib\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jagui\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dm_14rqt\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y2duvqsp\dlib\

What is going wrong?

Comment: you can try the solution in this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001837/problem-in-installing-python-library-face-recognition-on-windows-10-11/70044454#70044454

Answer (score 1):

https://pypi.org/project/face_recognition/#description:

Requirements

- macOS or Linux (**Windows not officially supported**, but might work)

Unofficial @masoudr’s Windows 10 installation guide (dlib + face_recognition): https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508