# problem in Installing (python Library) face_recognition on windows 10/11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, face-recognition

I am using python 3.9.9
pip 21.3.1

I am trying to install face_recognition

so I installed CMake
then when I tried to install dlib using command `pip install dlib` I got the following

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.22.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Prep

    aring metadata (setup.py) ... done
    Building wheels for collected packag

es: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hjnpx8xk'
       cwd: C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78dld3fg\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\
  Complete output (8 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext

  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zbjc8ulw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-78dld3fg\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext

    ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-78dld3fg\\dlib_098968d181654cc09e283aff4801a4b1\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zbjc8ulw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.**
```

and when I tried to install face_recognition using command  `pip install face_recognition`
I got the following:

```
Collecting face_recognition
  Using cached face_recognition-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 in c:\users\aenas\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from face_recognition) (0.3.0)
Collecting dlib>=19.7
  Using cached dlib-19.22.1.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Click>=6.0
  Using cached click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\aenas\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.21.4)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\aenas\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from face_recognition) (8.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\aenas\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from Click>=6.0->face_recognition) (0.4.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-elyfs9nv'
       cwd: C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cy9bzkon\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\
  Complete output (8 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext

  ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, Click, face-recognition
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oojov4ij\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cy9bzkon\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\
    Complete output (8 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'tools\python\dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext

    ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aenas\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-cy9bzkon\\dlib_8e45a10b6067402ab676a29d5bd742c8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-oojov4ij\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aenas\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Though I have tried many solution but none of them solved my problem

Comment: "*I installed CMake…*" Is it available in `%PATH%`? Can you run `cmake` in the terminal?

Comment: no I can not, but when I type the command `pip install cmake` I get the following: ```Requirement already satisfied: cmake in c:\users\aenas\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.21.4)```

Comment: Add directory where `cmake` resides to `%PATH%`.

Comment: could you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+directory+to+PATH

Comment: Thanks, I will try that now

Comment: it is added now, unfortunately, the problem isn't solved yet, I am still getting the same error

Comment: Can you run `cmake` in the terminal? If not — the `PATH` is still wrong. After adding directory with `cmake` to `PATH` you need to update `PATH` in all open terminals or close (exit) and re-start them. Then again check if `cmake` can be ran.

Comment: cmake can run now in the terminal , but when I try to install "dlib" or "face_recognition" it gives me the same error shown in the question

Comment: Install Visual Studio Build tools and then install

Comment: ok, I will try that

Comment: @Kris Thank you for the solution, I was doing something wrong, but now it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I solved the problem. These are the steps to download face_recognition Library:

### **1- install python:**

> in the command prompt write `python` and click Enter, this will open
> Microsoft store for you, "click download" or "install" to download and
> install python. "to check if it is downloaded or not type `python` in the
> command prompt

### 2- install pip if you do not have it:

> go to: https://pypi.org/project/pip-download/
> click download files. Now open the downloaded file, then click right click
> with the mouse and choose "open in windows terminal". now type the command
> `python get-pip.py`. now your pip should be installed, type `pip` in the
> terminal to check if it is installed

### 3-Install Visual Studio tools For C++

> go to: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ and download the community
> version of VS. after downloading install it and choose the following
> options in the installation page:
> [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVXLI.png) [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0msh.png)
>
> and choose install

### 4- installing cmake

> Enter the command `pip install cmake` and wait fo it to be installed.

### 5- Add cmake to the Path variable

> follow the instructions in the following link to know how to add
> something to your Path variable:
> https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/

### 6- Install dlib

> write the following command in the command prompt: `pip install dlib`

### 7- install face_recognition

> write the following command in the command prompt: `pip install face_recognition`

### 8- start your project in PyCharm

> click File click Sittings  in the search type "interpreter" choose
> "python interpreter" choose "show all" click the "+" sign choose
> system Interpreter choose the interpreter that its path starts with
> the "users" directory

That is the solution I used to fix my problem

Comment: This solution will work for windows. I am getting kind of same issue importing face_recognition in Mac M1.. do you know any solution about that?

Comment: @HaiderAbbas unfortunately no, sorry for that. Hope you can solve it soon.

Answer (score 1):

After doing all the steps described, I still get the following error:
Any help at all will be greatly appreciated!

```
Collecting dlib 
  Using cached dlib-19.24.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB) 
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done 

Installing collected packages: dlib
  DEPRECATION: dlib is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for dlib did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> dlib

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```