# Python face_recognition library import error

Tags: python, face-recognition

I wanted to try the `face_regognition` package in python, but I get this error and couldn't find a working solution online, I'im using M1 Mac by the way.

> ImportError:
> dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-39-darwin.so,
> 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace
> '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: @blackbishop Have you guys found any work around ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help you, but try the last step (step8) of this solution if you are using pycharm, it might help you

[problem in Installing (python Library) face_recognition on windows 10/11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70001837/problem-in-installing-python-library-face-recognition-on-windows-10-11/70044454#70044454)

I faced a similar problem after installing the library, and that is how I solved it