# face_recognition dlib error with CMake during installation

Tags: python, cmake, pip, face-recognition, dlib

I'm trying to download face_recognition for a project. Keep getting this error. Any ideas to fix it?

```
C:\>pip install face_recognition

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from face_recognition) (1.22.2)
  Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      -- The C compiler identification is unknown
      -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
        No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
        No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found
```

Comment: As it says, you do not have a C or C++ compiler installed... you can get Microsoft's Visual Studio compiler for free from their website: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/

Comment: hi, you can try this procedure if you are using windows https://stackoverflow.com/a/70044454/17424390